# how to find closely related values from a set?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, extremal-combinatorics

I have a set of values, for eg. {20, 1, 1, 21, 8, 22, 11, 40, 5, 21} and will need to find n closely related values. If n is 4 in the given example, the result should be {20, 21, 21, 22} because these are the closely related values (with least distance between them) in the given set.

It is possible to compare the number with each other and find the closely related ones. But this becomes cumbersome when the number of elements in set is large. 
Is there any optimal algorithm to do this?

Comment: Note that you have a multiset, not a set. There are no repeated items in a set.

Comment: @joffan Yes, it is a multiset

Comment: You can try to convert your problem to a TSP problem then you may be able to find an optimal algorithm.

Comment: @Ninja True, I was also more inclined to the same thought as yours. Was trying to see if there are any simpler and optimal algorithm that would serve the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way. For a multi-set of $n$ elements, selecting an $m$-subset:

1. Sort the multiset (this could be linear for integers or $n \log n$ for reals).
2. Take all differences of size $m$ in the sorted set (i.e. $e_{m}-e_1, e_{m+1} - e_2, \ldots$) and select the smallest one from these (a linear operation).

This last difference will represent $m$-subset of smallest radius.

Clearly, the answer need not be unique (e.g. a 2-subset from $\{1,2,2,1\}$ has 2 different answers of radius $0$). Total running time - $n \log n$.

Comment: Thanks. But there is a twist here.. Let us take the elements (sorted) as {1, 2, 5, 14, 21, 22, 32, 33, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 46, 49, 50, 58, 58, 59, 60}. In this case, there are more than 1 result set with 4 numbers as the result would be an m-subset with smallest radius as you mentioned.  1, 32, 33, 34, 37, 49, 58, 58, 59, 60 are the numbers then. How do we derive from this that {32, 33, 34, 37} as the final set because the sum of difference between these numbers is the smallest from the rest. Also please note that the numbers must be contiguous.

Comment: @Jithu that sorted set is output from step 1. in step 2 you take all 4-differences, i.e. $14-1-13, 21-2=19, 22-5=17, \ldots, 34-32=2, \ldots 60-58 = 2$ and from these you take the minimum, which gives you 2 candidates for the value of $2$: $\{32,33,33,34\}$ and $\{58,58,59,60\}$ - both are answers of equivalent goodness.

Comment: But how do we separate out two sets?

Comment: @Jithu what do you mean? the index of the numbers you compared (which should be preserved, and you should really be sorting ordered pairs `(value, index)` by first coordinate) will tell you the starting point of the set, and then you take $m-1$ more elements to the right to construct the entire set.